# Control which GCE VMs use dynamic routes in a GCP VPC?

Tags: routing, google-cloud-platform

I have a GCP VPC that receives dynamic routes from a BGP peering over a partner interconnect, but not all  GCE VM instances in my VPC should make use of those dynamic routes... Is there any way to control which VMs will actually use those routes?

When using *static* routes it is possible to control this by using [Network tags](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/add-remove-network-tags#interaction_with_routes), but for obvious reasons tags cannot be applied at route-level on *dynamic* routes... Another option would be to apply a network tag on the BGP peering - or on the partner interconnect - but I haven't found a way to do this yet (if it is possible at all).

Are there any other ways to "scope" usage of dynamic routes in GCP VPCs? As a last resort, I could switch to manual routing (if it works) or use a separate VPC, but that is far from ideal in my use case...

Answer (score 0):

Based on the documentation [1](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/routes#instancerouting), the dynamic routing is applicable to all VM instances in the same region as the Cloud Router if the VPC network is in regional dynamic routing mode, or all instances if the VPC network is in global dynamic routing mode.
Currently there is no way like the Custom Static Routing does, applying a corresponding network tag, to limit the routing advertisement to a specific VM instance pool.
So, in order to mitigate this issue as a better scenario to this, I suggest you use a custom static routing or firewall rules together with the network tags [3](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/add-remove-network-tags).
You can also open a Feature Request [4](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers) to them in order to have this feature available.